# Where is awesome Flutter snippet extension?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

Many tutorials recommend using awesome flutter snippet extension by Neevash Ramdial.
But i cannot find it in the VSC extension marketplace no more!
You guys having problem with this as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While trying to update the project with Flutter 3 support, the organization was accidentally deleted due to a tooling bug.

The plugin has since been reuploaded to the VSCode marketplace, but users will need to reload the extension since the IDs are different.

Very sorry for the inconvenience caused here

Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Nash.awesome-flutter-snippets

-- [Nash](https://twitter.com/nash0x7e2)

Comment: Thanks Nash!! Life saver. I was about to venture into learning to create snippets so I could get some of these updates for Flutter 3.

Answer (score -1):

Awesome Flutter Snippets is a collection of commonly used Flutter classes and methods. It increases your speed of development by eliminating most of the boilerplate code associated with creating a widget. Widgets such as `StreamBuilder` and `SingleChildScrollView` can be created by typing the shortcut `streamBldr` and `singleChildSV` respectively.

It is built-in in Android Studio/VsCode. You can try by using short keyword like when you'll create `StatefulWidget` you can type `stf` and it give you hint as `StatefulWidget`.

Comment: OOooooooooOOoo i must learn to read

Comment: try to code yourself and you'll know about `Flutter snippets`.